# Development system with MAMP won't run after MAMP upgrade?

Tags: mamp

I have a development system with MAMP and gulp and my localhost version of my website was running fine.  I upgraded MAMP from 3.5.2 to 4.4.1.  When I restarted MAMP it said it needed to upgrade the database, which I let it do.  Now when I try to start the website, it just spins at the localhost:6002 (for example) website address and the site will never launch.

Any thoughts on how to chase down this problem.

Answer (score 1):

The ports were changed to 7888 and 8888 and I needed to set them back to what I was currently using.